# copy strings from a few files and paste it into a new file in bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, bioinformatics, fasta

i have a few files with fasta data. all the files are in the same dir have a different name.
file1

```
>gene1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>gene2
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

file2

```
>gene1
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
>gene2
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

i want to create a new file for every gene. the file name will be the gene name and it should look like this

gene1

```
>file1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>file2
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the genes are only one line long, is there?

Comment: All genes are unwrapped fasta format. Every gene has one line

Comment: Are there the same genes in the same order in each file?

Comment: Yes with different snp / indel variations that I want to analyze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Tested and written with provided samples only.

```
awk '
/^>/{
  sub(/^>/,"")
  file=$0
  print ">"FILENAME >> (file)
  next
}
{
  print >> (file)
  close(file)
}
' file*
```

For provided samples it will create 2 output files named `gene1` and `gene2` as follows.

```
cat gene1
>file1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>file2
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

cat gene2
>file1
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
>file2
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

***Explanation:*** Adding an explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
/^>/{                              ##Checking a condition if a line starts from > as per samples.
  sub(/^>/,"")                     ##Substituting that starting > with NULL here.
  file=$0                          ##Creating a variable named file whose value is current line.
  print ">"FILENAME >> (file)      ##Printing string > and awk variable FILENAME to output file variable named file; created in previous line.
  next                             ##next will skip all further lines from here.
}                                  ##Closing BLOCK for /^>/ condition here.
{                                  ##Starting BLOCK for here which will be executed on each line of Input_file part from lines which start from >
  print >> (file)                  ##Printing current line to output file named variable file value here.
  close(file)                      ##Using close; to close the output file in back-end, to avoid too many files opened error.
}                                  ##Closing BLOCK as mentioned above for this program.
' file*                            ##Passing all files here.
```

Comment: where do i specify the input files ?

Comment: @ZivAttia, where `file*` is mentioned in my code at last. Put it like file* only if your real files have file1 file2 etc names and lemme know then.

Comment: every file has a different name

Comment: @ZivAttia, are they having same extensions file names etc?

Comment: @ZivAttia, try like `.*bam` once?

Answer (score 1):

for your problem, there are few presumptions, that

- each "gene" has one header, start with `>`
- then followed by one line content (or more)
- assume there are more than 2 file, more than 2 gene

that's the condition for any program to detect the pattern, and do the filtering / spliting

pesudo code

```
for files in folder
  for line in file
    if it's gene, save as target_file_name
    if not, push current_file_name and current_line to target_file_name
```

let me know if this meets your requirement, or you need further implementaiton / detail code, both `bash` or `awk` should work.